# Accessing Integrated Search Without F3

Tags: shortcut

All my F keys are predefined.  (I'm on an iMac and use the default Apple functions frequently.)  I've found multiple places that say F3 brings up Search in Blender.  It seems like almost everything in Blender can be reached in multiple ways, such as a keyboard shortcut, a menu, or through a pie menu or any of the bars at the side or top of an editor window.

How, other than F3, can I get to Blender's search function?  Or is there a way to add an icon somewhere I can click on to access it?

Comment: In the header menu Edit: Menu Search, and python operator: `bpy.ops.wm.search_menu()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it manually via `Edit > Menu Search...`

You could add the `Menu Search` to quick favorites by right clicking on it and selecting `Add to Quick Favorites`. Quick favorites can be accessed by pressing `Q`

You can also redefine your keyboard shortcuts in `Edit > Preferences > Keymap` (search for `Search Menu`)

Comment: Ah!  In the two books I'm using, one doesn't refer to search at all.  The other always uses the term "Integrated Search," and I kept looking everywhere for "Int...." for "Integrated Search.  Totally missed "Operator Search!"  Thanks - so much to learn in this program!  I've already added it to my Quick Favorites.  Much appreciated!